# insert stored procedure with set null parameters in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

I want to insert `null` parameter in some values, but I get the following error :

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>   System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue.get returned null.

The program is a `Windows Forms` application, and the code is as follows:

```
using (var context = new SamenEntities())
{
    person ppp = new person()
    {
        id = textBox1.Text.Trim(),
        name = textBox2.Text.Trim(),
        family = textBox3.Text.Trim(),
        birth_date = dateTimePicker1.Value,
        birth_provice = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()),
        note = richTextBox1.Text.Trim(),
        img_personal = ImageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image),
        date_register = DateTime.Now
    };

    context.persons.Add(ppp);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

How to enter `null` value or enter default value from SQL server?

Comment: What are the fields you're trying to set as `null`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By look at the exception, it says that the `ComboBox` does not have any value selected. It is not about SQL Server not accepting `null` at this point.

With that information, you should check that one value is selected, meaning it is not `null`, like this:

```
object selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedValue;

if(selectedValue != null)
{
    ppp.birth_provice = Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue.ToString()),
}
```

On top of that, you may want to consider using `Int32.TryParse` to make sure the selected value is an actual integer.